# Journey not displaying triggered results

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have two issues:

1. When I push content into a data extension associated in contact builder as an attribute and start the interaction event with automation studio, contacts don't get injected into the interaction.
2. I have 2 instances where contacts where injected, but when I go to see the trigger results, it shows zero results.

Any insights on this will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

there are several different reasons why this could be occurring.

Firstly, regarding Contacts not entering the Interaction from Automation Studio, bear in mind that only new Contacts added to a Data Extension will enter an Interaction. **Even if you delete an Automation and create a new one**, if the Data Extension record has previously entered an Interaction, they will be ignored.

The best method for troubleshooting both of your issues is to start by checking Contacts Administration in Journey Builder. Do you see records in there? If so, are there any related error messages? You mention that Contacts are injected. How do you know this? Are you looking at the total population that has entered the Interaction?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Eliot! I have the journey working, injecting contacts and receiving messages. However, when I go to contact history or when I try to see the Trigger Results, I don't see any data in there.

Comment: Are you on the S7 instance by any chance? I opened a support case last week with exactly the same issue (#01401645) and it appears they are aware of this and investigating, but I haven't had an update yet.

Comment: FYI, just had an update that this is still unresolved and they are working on a fix. All of the counts and information on the running Interaction itself should be accurate (when you view the Interaction), you just can't see the detail in Trigger results or Contact Administration.

Comment: yes! s7 instance, nice good to know!